# Author biography information when submitting papers to IEEE Access

Tags: paper-submission, open-access, ieee

I'm about to submit a paper to IEE Access. Since the journal requires author bios at the end of the paper, I have added all the bio information of co-authors.
However, when I was preparing the submission, the submission system (manuscriptcentral) asked me to submit a separate file for the author bios (see attached figure).
[image]

It seems strange to me because the author bios are already added to the paper, and I think the system is going to combine submitted PDF files in a unique one, which will duplicate the author information.

Have you ever experienced that, and how do you solve it?
Thanks.

Comment: Why does this need to be solved?  Just provide the info. It does not hurt your submission.  A reviewer will not reject a paper just because they are two sets of authors info.

Comment: I think the same, but it seems a bit strange to me as the proof will have two sets of authors info

Comment: One way is to remove the biography information from the manuscript.

Comment: Hello, can you share your experience? What have you done in this regard?

Comment: I eventually added bio info to the paper and also had a separate file.
The paper was accepted already.

Comment: Is adding biographies required or optional? It seems optional to me.